# Error when I click login button in react app

Tags: reactjs, azure, react-native, azure-active-directory

I have a problem where by when I click on the login button, it does not show the sign in popup for the application. I noticed the console of the inspect element shows an error called BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API.

I have tried changing the authority link, checking everything needed is installed but all leads to a dead end and it still doesn't work.

This is my app.js script

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {config } from './Config';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       error: null,
       isAuthenticated: false,
       user: {} 
    };

    this.login = this.login.bind(this)
    // Initialize the MSAL application object
    this.publicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: config.appId,
        redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
        authority: config.authority 
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
      }
    });
  }

  async login(){
    try {
      // Login via popup
      await this.publicClientApplication.loginPopup(
          {
            scopes: config.scopes,
            prompt: "select_account"
          });
  
      this.setState({isAuthenticated:true})
      }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
        error: err
      });
    }
  }

  logout() { 
    this.publicClientApplication.logoutRedirect();
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
          <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo'/
          {this.state.isAuthenticated ?<p> 
            Successful logged in
          </p>:
          <p>
            <button onClick={() => this.login()}>Login Button</button
          </p>
          }
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

This is my config.js script

```
export const config = {
    appId: 'b52119f1-3d04-47fe-bf06-022b7e8d74a3',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    scopes: [
        'user.read'
    ],
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/87ff9ae9-e18b-4770-8820-8890e68a65c6'
};
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code and was able to click on **Login** button. It showed the sign in popup for my application.

**Code** :

**src/App.js** :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import AuthButton from './AuthButton';

function App() {
  const { accounts, instance } = useMsal();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>MSAL React App</h1>
        {accounts.length === 0 ? (
          <AuthButton msalInstance={instance} />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>Welcome, {accounts[0].name}</p>
            <button onClick={() => instance.logout()}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/AuthButton.js** :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { config } from './Config';

function AuthButton({ msalInstance }) {
  const login = async () => {
    try {
      await msalInstance.loginPopup({
        scopes: config.scopes,
        prompt: 'select_account'
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AuthButton;
```

**src/Config.js** :

```js
export const config = {
    appId: '<app_id>',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'user.read'],
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>',
  };
```

**src/index.js** :

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import App from './App';
import { config } from './Config';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: config.appId,
    redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
    authority: config.authority,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <App />
    </MsalProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**package.json** :

```json
{
  "name": "my-msal-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A basic React application with MSAL integration",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.16.1", 
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.0.1",    
    "antd": "^4.16.13",             
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Below is my application in my Active Directory.

[image]

**Output** :

It runs successfully as below:

[image]

I got the below output in the browser with the above URL.

[image]

I clicked on **Login** button and chose my existing account as below,

[image]

I got my application below, then I clicked on **Accept**.

[image]

Comment: Compiled with problems: × ERROR in ./src/App.js 85:0-44 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@azure/msal-react' in 'C:\Users\SGG92449\mytestapp\src' ERROR in ./src/index.js 25:0-49 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@azure/msal-react' in 'C:\Users\SGG92449\mytestapp\src'

Comment: @Kim Above error is a package error, use this command to install it **npm install @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-react** .

Comment: @Kim I updated my answer with the **package.json** file. You can try it.

Comment: I see, I installed the 2 packages you listed and the app works like a charm, thank you so much. If you don't mind, could you explain what the code does? Like how does it show the popup and stuff. I'm new to the react framework.

Comment: Also if can let me know like what was wrong with my code that make it showed that error?

Comment: @Kim The error in your code was due to using a class component instead of a functional component with hooks, which is the recommended approach for integrating MSAL with React.

Comment: Oh I see so I was using the wrong component to do login authentication. Thanks.