# Customizing Error Messages for Azure AD SSO Authentication in React.js with @azure/msal-react

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory

I'm implementing Single Sign-On (SSO) authentication with Azure AD in my React.js application using @azure/msal-react. Currently, when a user who is not present in the Azure AD group tries to authenticate, Azure returns the default error message: "Sorry but we’re having trouble signing you in." along with an AADSTS error code.

Is there a way to customize this error message or handle it more gracefully within my application? I've attempted to access error.errorMessage, but it only becomes available once the popup is closed. I've also looked into using localizedString, but documentation on this feature is sparse. Any insights or alternatives would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Login Code:
const login = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await instance.loginPopup({
      scopes: ["profile", "email"],
    });
    if (res.IdToken) {
      navigate('/about');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

In this code, clicking the login button triggers SSO authentication directly from Azure AD. If the user is not available in the AD group, I receive an error in a popup with the default message. I want to customize this message or redirect the user to my own error page instead of showing that popup. However, accessing err.errorMessage only works after the popup is closed, which is not ideal for displaying a custom error message during the authentication process.

I'm open to any suggestions on how to achieve this customization in my React.js application using @azure/msal-react. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your code in the question?

Comment: Check my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77049267/error-when-i-click-login-button-in-react-app/77050199#77050199) for login with reactjs app using msal.

Comment: @DasariKamali I saw your code , you’re checking for account and displaying the button am I right ??

Comment: Yes Rohan. If possible, can you share your code in the question?

Comment: @DasariKamali, updated the question with code. I want to show the custom error message instead of error message providing by azure or I want to alter the message inside the popup. Have a look on following post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1191236/customise-or-catch-aadsts50105-error-page-(msal-re which is what I am trying to achieve.